estoy usando PUBLICATION de posgres pero al interntar modificar los datos me da error
Quiero replicar una base de datos en otra en un sistema local; por el momento tengo dos base de datos en postgressql. La primera se llama publicaciones (en esta se hacen las publicaciones de las tablas o lo que deseo enviar a la otra base de datos) las segunda bd es suscripcion (en estas se suscriben a las publicaciones de las bd publicaciones).
Sucede que, cuando publico una tabla con ciertos filtros, la base de datos no me deja editar los datos; me arroja un error cuando intento modificar los datos con un UPDATE o eliminar:
Esta es la estructura de ambas tablas :
--TABLA t2

    CREATE TABLE t2(d int, e int, f int, PRIMARY KEY(d));
 
--DATA TABLA t2

    INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1,821,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4), (6,6,6),(7,7,7);

--Comando para la Publicacion: 

    CREATE PUBLICATION p2 FOR TABLE t1, t2 WHERE (e = 99);

--SUSCRIPCION : 

    CREATE SUBSCRIPTION s2 CONNECTION 'host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=publicaciones connect_timeout=10 password=admin sslmode=prefer application_name=s2' PUBLICATION p2;


ahora despues de hacer las publicaciones intento usar la consulta Update:
 UPDATE t2 SET e=99 where d=2;

El error que me arroja es:

ERROR: La columna usada en la expresión
WHERE de la publicación no es parte de la identidad de
replicación.cannot update table "t2" ERROR: cannot update table "t2"
SQL state: 42P10 Detail: La columna usada en la expresión WHERE de la
publicación no es parte de la identidad de replicación. ERROR:  La
columna usada en la expresión WHERE de la publicación no es parte de
la identidad de replicación.cannot update table "t2"
ERROR:  cannot update table "t2" SQL state: 42P10 Detail: La columna
usada en la expresión WHERE de la publicación no es parte de la
identidad de replicación.

Ahora, cuando quiero editar los datos para ver si replica me arroja el error. No se me ven reflejados los cambios en la tabla.

Creo que es buena idea que incluyas la sentencia de actualización que estás utilizando (el update o delete). Saludos.

El Error puede ser descriptivo, debes tener la columna como parte de la indetidad de replication, creo que para eso lo puedes lograr cambiando el IDENTITY de la tabla a FULL, por ejemplo:
ALTER TABLE t2 REPLICA IDENTITY FULL

Elimina todo y vuelve a crear la tabla y antes de crear la PUBLICATION y SUBSCRIPTION realiza el ALTER de la tabla

cree la tabla de nuevo con el siguiente codigo: CREATE TABLE t2 (
d INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, e INT, f INT,PRIMARY KEY(d)
); cuando creo la PUBLICATION con el filtro de datos me da el error

Intentaste lo que te comenté? El ALTER TABLE t2 REPLICA IDENTITY FULL, por favor intenta eso

usando exatamete los que me dices me arroja este error: ERROR:  no existe la relación «t2»
SQL state: 42P01

A ver, hazlo todo desde el principio, si te dice que la tabla t2 no existe, es por no estas en la base de datos correcta o eliminaste tu tabla del ejemplo llamada t2

perfecto, si funciono me ubique en la tabla le, escribi :SELECT * FROM public.t2 espere que me dieran los resultados y despues use tu consulta : ALTER TABLE t2 REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;  ya puedo editar sin problemas muchas gracias

Puedes marcar la respuesta como solucion, eso le puede servir a otros que tengan un caso similar el tuyo, asi funciona stackoverflow ;-)
